# How to remove "catalog/view/.." links from products?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, url

So despite having *Use Categories Path for Product URLs* checked to yes I still see some products with the ugly URL like **/catalog/product/view/id/12019/s/** - the majority of products have the expected SEO-friendly url's but quite a few still don't. Why does this continue to happen and would it be possible to correct this in bulk? I have a few thousand products that have this URL structure.

Answer (score 1):

Reindex and clear your cache. Also check if you have mod_rewrite enabled if you are using Apache.

Comment: I tried this and am still not seeing the updated URL's. I also do have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Try reindexing via SSH if possible and only the Catalog rewrite index.

Comment: Does it actually matter? I only checked the Catalog rewrite index and it didn't work. I don't have access to SSH unfortunately :(

Answer (score -1):

check also if you have .htaccess in your root.